# setting up a dynamic server

Tags: android, ios, mobile, proxy, webserver

Hi I'm a web developer working in a start-up company who works on a mobile app (iOS and Android) the app have a db on a web platform and I want to make a static mid server which will send the clients the address (on login) they should work with.
for example if the client need to make HTTP requestst to the address xx.yy.zz he will first ask for it from a static address lets say aa.bb.cc (that basiaclly means that if the address for http requests is being changed it's value should only need to be changed in aa.bb.cc and not on the client side - which dont need to upgrade or do nothing).

any suggestions, comments, ways to implemet ,guides etc we be highly appreciated, tnx in advance =)

p.s 
it's quite similar to proxy the only difference is im not saving cache but managing a db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand what your problem is. If you send the client the address xx.yy.zz it should use for further server-communication, the client simply has to store that xx.yy.zz somewhere and then use it as the server-address to connect to.
So perhaps you want to know how to store the address? In Android you can store it in the Preferences or keep it in a variable in your Application and so on... there's plenty of examples how to store some data for the apps lifetime.

Comment: No, I know how to work with shared preference.
I can give you a short exmaple so you can understand better maybe you will have agood exmaple for it:
say have a web platform and an app both communicate with json object (app make http request to the web and get responds with json) in any case I move the web platform to another server I should update the dns to the new server ip plus communicating directly to a db have security issues, I thought to make an intermidate server (aa.bb.cc) that sends the address to communicate with (xx.yy.zz) on run time storing it only for the communication

Comment: Well normally you'd set up a server that has a domain name, e.g. `example.com` and the app would connect to that server using the domain name. So when you have to change the server, simply change the dns entries for example.com so that it points to the new server. I don't think that there are any security issues with that.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very useful and right. Actually it happens in every application having some server access. The concept is called webserver-appserver configuration and this is useful as per the security concerns also.

Application should not go directly to your AppServer it may be risky some times. So what you can do make an Apache webserver as your static server and put your Application Server behind a firewall.So while making a request from device, what device has to know only the webserver IP and port and then the webserver have a configuration file to redirect the request to your Application Server (with IP and port) that will be unknown for the device.

Go through this url for better understanding of redirection from Apache Web Server to another server, not a big task you just need to edit the configuration files:

http://library.linode.com/web-servers/apache/configuration/redirecting-urls

if you want security for your appserver its better not to use the default port(8080) between webserver and appserver use some specified port and open them only for communication(take request from webserver sending the response) between them  not all.

and if you want know more about security and ports go through this:

http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2010/07/how-to-manage-windows-firewall-settings-using-group-policy/

Comment: Thanks! that was what I was looking for! =)
any good tutorials you know or more reading I can do?